# Facebook like button not show with document.write();

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have a sample code:

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    window.checkDoesLike = function() {
      FB.api({ method: 'pages.isFan', page_id: '40796308305' }, function(resp) {
        if (resp) {
            alert("You have like this pages");
        } else {
            //<![CDATA[
            document.write('<fb:like href="http://www.facebook.com/coca-cola" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" width="450" action="like" font="arial" colorscheme="light"></fb:like>');
            //]]>
        }
      });
    };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="checkDoesLike()">
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function(d){
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
    }(document));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I run code, facebook like not show (Though i have not like in page http://www.facebook.com/coca-cola), how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [FB.XFBML.parse()](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/) after you add XFBML tags to the page

Comment: I has call FB.XFBML.parse(document.write('like here')); but result not change

Comment: You need call the method **after** you write the XFBML to the page